# How do you keep confidential info (e.g testing passwords) out of version control?

Tags: security, version-control, mercurial

Some of my programs require some confidential data (authentication mainly) to work properly. 
I often put my own credentials in the `main()` of the sourcecode when developing and testing to see if my code works, and remove them when all is OK. However, it's easy to forget removing them.

**What is a good approach to prevent these confidential data from ending up in a version control commit?**

I use Mercurial (and Python).

I've been thinking of:

- automatic running some sensitive-data checking script on commit, which aborts if it finds some specific strings (doesn't seem fool proof, requires maintaining the sensitive strings)
- storing the confidential data somewhere else (where?, how to practically import/use them?).
- using a testing branch (but doesn't really solve the problem)
- providing the confidential data as command line arguments (too unpractical)

Comment: Why are your tests using confidential databases?

Comment: @Arafangion: I don't mean tests like in 'unit tests'. By test, I meant "when I try out some changes in my code", i.e. when I develop. I've modified my question to make this more clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put things like authentication data in a config file, then add that config file to the set of ignored files in your VCS (in Mercurial, that's `.hgignore`).

Comment: I use a variant on this - I create a base config file and add it to version control. The base version has simple, non-sensitive configuration for the app as run in development: things like DB names and filesystem paths. At runtime my app loads this file, but then looks for a secondary file with production settings, including sensitive information, in the same directory. Anything in this file overrides the same properties in the base file. I mark this filename as ignored in VC so it doesn't accidentally get added.